# Functions drastically slowing down calculation time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table where I'm using my custom made functions, made in `VBA`. I have to mention that I am using these functions inside cells, not in a macro. Everything works just fine, however, I am noticing a dramatic slowdown in calculation time. To be honest, I am using my function in about 200 cells, but still I don't see how it can reason such a memory hungry spreadsheet. Also my 2 functions are very basic, one is a plain vanilla `isExist`(value) search in a 5 cells range (no binary or other fast search algos). The other function is a modified `dateDiff`, so I can use it as a cell function (for some reason dateDiff does not show as a cell formula). Anyways, can someone tell me why a vba function  would be so memory hungry when used in cell as a formula, and how can I optimize this?

```
Function existsInArray(array_to_search As range, value_to_exist As String) As Boolean
    For Each value In array_to_search
        If value_to_exist = value Then
            existsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    existsInArray = False
End Function


Function dayOfTheYear(begining_of_year_date As Date, to_date As Date) As Integer
    dayOfTheYear = CInt(DateDiff("d", begining_of_year_date, to_date)) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Can you post some example data and your code?

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: @aduguid sure, I've just edited my code in

Comment: @aduguid , see my code. let me known if you think my code could be the problem

Comment: Why would you use a UDF rather than native functions, which are almost always faster? BTW it's DATEDIF in a worksheet.

Comment: how many elements are actually present in your array?

Comment: The `existsInArray` can simply be done using a `COUNTIF`. This will truely be faster. Example `=COUNTIF(A1:C100, "xyz")>0` is the same as `=existsInArray(A1:C100, "xyz")`

Comment: @Tanmay Gawankar  like12 cells, 6 of them are empty

Comment: @Rory datediff might be in your xl, not in mine, donno why, but that's the case

Comment: @dre_84w934 its `datedif` single `f`

Comment: @Axel Richter , right, the problem is that I have more than one string value to verify, 6 in total

Comment: @TanmayGawankar I do not have datedif either, after typing =date, I got 2 options date value or date

Comment: @TanmayGawankar `DATEDIF` is a worksheet function (undocumented for many years); `DateDiff` is a VBA function.

Comment: This is the kind of problem that requires examining both the data and the code in order to come to a definitive answer. Otherwise we are all just guessing. I suggest you create a workbook (with sensitive information removed) that demonstrates the problem, and then upload it to some public file sharing site (that does not require registration); then edit your question to include a link to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't analyze completely without seeing how the UDFs are being used, but having code loop over ranges can be very slow.  For example:

```
Public Function MyUdf(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        ' do something that calculates MyUdf
        MyUdf = 1
    Next r
End Function
```

will examine and process each cell in `rng`.  If the user puts something like:

```
=MyUdf(A:A)
```

in a cell, it will process every cell in the **entire column**.

To limit the extent of the looping, you can use something like:

```
Public Function MyUdf2(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, RNG2 As Range
    Set RNG2 = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)
    For Each r In RNG2
        ' do something that calculates MyUdf
        MyUdf2 = 1
    Next r
End Function
```

That way you may end up processing thousands of cells rather than millions.

Anther possible speedup technique is to create VBA arrays to process the data rather than use cells directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default, UDF's (User Defined Functions) in Excel VBA are not volatile. They are only recalculated when any of the function's arguments change. A volatile function will be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet.

Turn Off Automatic Calculation

vba performanceSet the Calculation mode to xlCalculationManual so that no calculations are carried out within the Excel Workbook until the Calculation mode is changed back to xlCalculationAutomatic or by running Application.Calculate:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Turn Off Screen Updating

vba performancePrevent Excel from updating the Excel screen until this option is changed to True:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

The XLSB format vs. XLSM

vba performanceA known way to improve Excel VBA speed and efficiency, especially fore large Excel files, is to save your Workbooks in binary XLSB format.